# 'System/' file not found ? Running c++ on Xcode

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, system

I'm facing this issue at line no 3 `'System/' file not found` and on line 5 `Expected ';' after top level declarator` while debugging this c++ program on Xcode. This is my first time on Xcode

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <System>
using namespace System;
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args){
    Console::Clearc();
    Console::SetCursorPosition(5,5);
    putchar('*');
    Console::ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That looks like managed [C++-CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) which is a Microsoft extension of C++ for the [.NET framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework). If you want to learn plain standard C++, then I suggest you [find a good beginners book to read](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: C or C++? Why both the tags?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  So now do I need to change Xcode to another IDE?

Comment: No, you need to learn plain simple C++.

Comment: The problem is that `C++` and `C++/CLI` are different languages. Just like `Java` and `JavaScript` they only have half their name in common. The code is totally different.